# How to set System.Windows.Controls.Image as static in XAML in a WPF Desktop Application

Tags: c#, wpf, image, static

I'm needing to set System.Windows.Controls.Image in the MainWindow.xaml as a static object so that I can change the source from a static method at run-time.

I know that you can use ContentControl for objects such as TextBox but this will not work for System.Windows.Controls.Image.

I only just learned about ContentControl yesterday so i'm now getting into another area of coding I know little of.

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Label x:Name="label1" x:Key="label1"/>
    <Style x:Key="labels" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#B3B3B3" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource label1}" Style="{StaticResource labels}"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
var label1 = Application.Current.Resources["label1"] as Label;
            label1.Content = "This is label1";
```

I am needing to change the image source from a static method but I am needing the more optimal approach.

```
private static System.Windows.Controls.Image staticimage1 = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();

staticimage1 = image1;
```

This just seems like a hack to me and doing this in WPF seems to me to defeat the whole XAML portion of things (too much code behind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a named Image element in your MainWindow, like

```
<Image x:Name="image"/>
```

you can access it from a static method via the static `Application.Current` property:

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).image.Source
    = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));
```

Comment: Yes, that is quite optimal and does exactly as I need. Thank you so much.